# When does std::future get executed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

When a thread is created with the launch policy set as [`std::launch::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch), the description given on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) is

> a new thread is launched to execute the task asynchronously

If I have some arbitrary function

```
double Foo(double i)
{
    return i * 5.0;
}
```

And I set up an `async` call like so

```
std::vector<double> values{5.0, 2.3, 7.1, 4.8, 1.5};
std::vector<std::future<double>> answers;
for (double value : values)
{
    answers.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                                 Foo,
                                 value));
}
```

When I call `std::accumulate` like so:

```
double total = std::accumulate(begin(answers),
                               end(answers),
                               0.0,
                               [](double x, std::future<double>& t){return x + t.get();});
```

When do each of the threads kick off their execution? Did they start as soon as they were added to `answers`? Or do they wait until their `get` is invoked? If so, did I just force them to execute sequentially since their `get` is called in the order that `accumulate` executes them? In other words, did I just waste my time setting up these futures, then force them to run synchronously?

*Note*
The function `Foo` was just some example, the actual function I'm using does more work.

Comment: `get` waits until the result is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, they are started when you create the `future`.  It may only be scheduled for execution, or might actually be kicked off before the call to `async` returns.

There may be some attempt to keep only a certain number of threads running at a time (at least initially) with thread pooling etc, but that is a quality of implementation issue, and getting that right without being more intrusive or requiring more from the called function is hard.

The standard does not mandate anything close to that level of behavior, but in practice, async asyncs are actually async.

Answer (score 2):

The threads will be kicked off as soon as you call `std::async`. As such, your threads will run concurrently.

To quote [cpp-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> If the async flag is set (i.e. policy & std::launch::async != 0),
>   then async executes the function f on a new thread of execution (with
>   all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by std::thread(f,
>   args...), except that if the function f returns a value or throws an
>   exception, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the
>   std::future that async returns to the caller.

Comment: The spec has generally not been interpreted as implying an execution schedule, only a promise of concurrency, and so it is possible for implementations to use a thread pool. `The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.`  (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: @kfsone Yes, but what do you want to imply by that in the context of the question?

Comment: The question has been edited since your answer, but the point is that the threads are *not* guaranteed to be kicked off instantly. There may be a queue.

Comment: @kfsone I don't see any updates. The question is about whether they will be started before `get` or not. A threadpool really makes no difference. It's like taking the OS into account which could delay the scheduling of the thread.

Comment: just a hunch where he is going with the question.